# Probability of arranging 12 identical objects into 3 different boxes in such a way that one particular box has exactly three objects?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For solving above problem I have used classical approach for probability calculation i.e Number of Favorable . Moves/Total number of Move.

> Total Number of Moves as per the star and bar method will be n+r-1
>   Choose r-1 i.e  (14 C  2 ).

Number of Favorable moves will be equal to Number of ways of distributing 9 identical balls into 2 different boxes as chosen box will have exactly three balls.

> Number of Favorable moves will be 10 C 1.
>
> P=(14 C 2)/(10 C 1)

But as per the solution mentioned answer will be 55/3(2/3)^11.

They have solved this problem as per the binomial distribution. If X is random variable denoting number of balls in that Particular box the answer will be P(X=3)=12C3 p^3(1-p)9.

where p is the probability  of selecting that particular box and 1-p will be the probability of selecting other boxes.

Why my approach is not correct. or is there something that I am not getting.
Please suggest.

Comment: Not clear what "probability" you have in mind.  Are you saying that each object has an equal probability of going into any of the three boxes?  If so, then Stars and Bars has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Probability that a particular box will have exactly identical item and yes each object has an equal probability of going into any of the three boxes

Comment: Right, so Stars and Bars is irrelevant.  The distributions aren't equi-probable.  $(12,0,0)$ is a lot less likely than $(4,4,4)$, say.